# Avoid windows security pop up on starrting Outllook with a sharepoint connected list?

Tags: list, sharepoint-enterprise, outlook, windows-authentication

I have a sharepoint contacts list that I had connected to Outlook and now everytime my Colleagues or I try ro open up outlook it prompts us for our credentials.

Is it possible to make it use windows authentication automatically without presenting the user witht hte credential propmt every single time. They have grown annoyed!

Please advise. 
Thanks

Comment: Do you get login credentials when you browse to the site for the first time? I'm 95% sure Outlook/Office uses IE's security settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem dissappeared once I added the sharepoint site to the trusted sites in IE.